# PHP: fwrite not working in foreach loop (due to an image link?)

Tags: php, html, foreach, fwrite

I am a beginner in PHP. I found this very weird problem:

```
<?php 
$datei = fopen("newUserTTT.txt", "w+");

foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    $string = $key."=".$value;
    echo $string;
    fwrite($datei, $string);    
}
//fputs($datei, "test");
//fwrite($datei, "test");
fclose($datei); ?>
```

The problem is that the `fwrite` in the loop does not work on my website. If i only execute this little code it works fine. But embedded in my website it doesn't work anymore. The `fwrite` outside the loop works fine.

Now the thing that confuses me even more: In the HTML I have a
`<img...>` and also an external stylesheet.

If I comment out this two lines suddenly `fwrite` works again. But these two lines don't contain any PHP code. The only thing I can imagine, is that these are the only two lines that are using files from the directory...

Any ideas?

Comment: AND the echo $string works fine in the loop?

Comment: Yes, it, shows that thing that i actually want to have in the file. 
I also tried to replace the variable with a simple string. 
It only works if i comment out the stylsheet and image....

Comment: There must be a syntax error somewhere in your img or stylesheet code ...

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue. I have a fwrite inside a foreach loop and it is writing random data to file. Although, if I do echo of the same text just before fwrite, I get correct output on browser. Have wasted quite a few hours to figure out what is going wrong, but no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

If your fwrite works fine outside the loop, why don't you use it there? like this :

```
<?php
$datei = fopen('newUserTTT.txt','w+');
$string = '';
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    $string.=$key.'='.$value;
}
fwrite($datei,$string);
fclose($datei); ?>
```

hope it helps!

Comment: I just tried it out and was pretty sure it will work... 
Guess what, it didnt :(
I can "echo" the string right before it writes that string in the file, and it shows exactly the thing i want. But the file stays empty. I can see the last edit of the file just happend, so it definetly touches the file, but it doesnt write something....

Comment: what about fopen(file,"a+") does it change something? Your fopen(...,"w+") makes file empty before writing in it.

Comment: and did you try "fputs"? Idk where your error comes from, but the code above should work...

Comment: I just validated my html and css, both no problem. I just discoverd that the picture is not shown also the css is not use, kind of like the php/html file has no access to the rest of the directory...

Comment: OKay, now i just found it. It was really an error with my code, the $_GET string was broken due to an formular error in the previous form. Thank you for your help :)